# Fallo al crear volumen LVM. Device not found /dev/sdxy (or ignored by filtering)

Tags: linux

Tengo una máquina con CentOS 7.3.1611 y un oVirt Hosted Engine.

Quiero añadir un nuevo disco (sdb) al volume group para extenderlo para así poder crear otro logical volume donde poder crear máquinas virtuales.

Aquí muestro el resultado de hacer un fdisk sobre el disco en cuestión:

```
[root@host1 ~]# fdisk /dev/sdb 
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Orden (m para obtener ayuda): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 300.1 GB, 300069052416 bytes, 586072368 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Identificador del disco: 0x7a33815f

Disposit. Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/sdb1            2048   586072367   293035160   8e  Linux LVM
```

La partición /dev/sdb1 se muestra al ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
[root@host1 ~]# cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

8    0    293036184    sda  
8    1    1024    sda1  
8    16    293036184    sdb  
8    17    293035160    sdb1
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el comando para crear el physical volume con "pvcreate /dev/sdb1" el resultado es el siguiente:

```
[root@host1 ~]# pvcreate /dev/sdb1

Device /dev/sdb1 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

He revisado el fichero `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` por el tema de los filtros, pero no tengo ningun filtro que me haga pensar que LVM esta descartando el dispositivo (todas las lineas de filtros están comentadas). He reiniciado la máquina cuando he creado la partición antes de ejecutar pvcreate. He buscado en google por el error pero no doy con la solución.

Comment: El idioma de este sitio es el español.

Comment: Cierto, Ya he traducido la pregunta. - toledano

Comment: Gracias Ivan Botero